# Unittest test get_arguments with required argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, arguments, command-line-arguments

I use coverage.py and unittest to test get_arguments

need_to_test.py

```
def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--num', type=str, default='0')
    ....
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_arguments()
    ...
```

test_need_to_test.py

```
import need_to_test
class Test_need_to_test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.args = need_to_test.get_arguments()
      
    def test_get_arguments(self):
        #test self.args here
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'))
```

But when i run

```
coverage run test_need_to_test.py -c file_path
```

the error occured

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'file_path'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

How do i coverge or test get_arguments function using unittest, or in unittest we don't need to test get_arguments() just skip it?

Comment: The easiest way to test is to explicitly pass in the arguments when you call it: `if __name__ == "__main__": args = get_arguments(sys.argv[1:])`. Then you can provide your own examples, as shown in https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#beyond-sys-argv.

Comment: Here's an example where I've done just that: https://github.com/textbook/eleanor-rigbot/blob/d3ce23c371718f1a8c42d9ca881bd12da1c84514/tests/test_arg_parsing.py